# MS Access 2010: Automatically Filters all the records depending on the user logged in

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a database in Microsoft Access 2010 where when a user logged in the database, the user will only see records that is related to him or her. I've put a criteria in the record's query specifically in `IssuingManager` field which is `[Forms]![frm_Home]![txtUser]` but I always get `enter parameter value` when I run it. `txtUser` is an invisible text box in my main form so the records will have a reference on which records to filter. My main goal is to limit the user's data to their own records and hide or block them to others. I am new to access and still learning it. Any help or other ways I can filter the data or limit it to the records that is only related to the current user logged in is a big help.

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT AdditionalFields.Status, tbl_NTE.CaseIDNo, tbl_NTE.EmployeeName, 
tbl_PAH.DPosition, tbl_NTE.Function, tbl_NTE.IssuingManager, 
tbl_NTE.ApprovingManager, tbl_NTE.ObjectOfViolation, tbl_NTE.Offense, 
tbl_NTE.ClassPenalty, tbl_NTE.CorrectiveActionPenalty, 
tbl_NTE.ObjectOfViolation2, tbl_NTE.Offense2, tbl_NTE.ClassPenalty2, 
tbl_NTE.ObjectOfViolation3, tbl_NTE.CorrectiveActionPenalty2, 
tbl_NTE.Offense3, tbl_NTE.ClassPenalty3, tbl_NTE.ObjectOfViolation4, 
tbl_NTE.CorrectiveActionPenalty3, tbl_NTE.Offense4, tbl_NTE.ClassPenalty4, 
tbl_NTE.CorrectiveActionPenalty4, tbl_NTE.DatesWhenActsWasWereCommited, 
tbl_NTE.DatesWhenActsWasWereDiscovered, tbl_NTE.NTEDate, 
tbl_NTE.NTELastDateModified, tbl_NTE.NTELastTimeModified, 
tbl_NTE.NTELastUser, tbl_PAH.PAHDate, tbl_PAH.PAHLastDateModified, 
tbl_PAH.PAHLastTimeModified, tbl_PAH.PAHLastUser, tbl_NCA.NCADate, 
tbl_NCA.NCALastDateModified, tbl_NCA.NCALastTimeModified, 
tbl_NCA.NCALastUser, tbl_NTE.EndorsedNTENoticeToHR, 
tbl_NTE.EndorsementOfNTEToIS, tbl_NTE.DateReceivedNTEByTheEmployee, 
tbl_NTE.SubmissionOfWEtoIS, tbl_NTE.SubmissionOfWEtoHRER, 
tbl_NTE.InitialDecision, tbl_PAH.ScheduleForPAH, tbl_PAH.Recommendation, 
tbl_PAH.EndorsementOfDecisionNoticeFromPAHCommitteeChairToHR, 
tbl_PAH.EndorsementOfFinalizedPAHRecommendationToIS, 
tbl_NCA.EndorsementOfDA2ToHRForReview, tbl_NCA.EndorsementOfReviewedDA2ToIS, 
tbl_NCA.EmployeeAcceptanceOfDecision, 
AdditionalFields.DescriptionOfPenaltyFinalDecision, 
AdditionalFields.ApplicableDatesofEffectivity, AdditionalFields.Remarks, 
AdditionalFields.RunningTAT, AdditionalFields.TAT, tbl_NTE.EHRID, 
tbl_NTE.IssuingManagerEmailAddress, tbl_NTE.WrittenExplanationDueDate, 
tbl_NTE.OffenseNo5, tbl_NTE.Offense5, tbl_NTE.ObjectOfViolation5, 
tbl_NTE.ClassPenalty5, tbl_NTE.CorrectiveActionPenalty5, tbl_NTE.OffenseNo6, 
tbl_NTE.Offense6, tbl_NTE.ObjectOfViolation6, tbl_NTE.ClassPenalty6, 
tbl_NTE.CorrectiveActionPenalty6, tbl_NTE.OffenseNo7, tbl_NTE.Offense7, 
tbl_NTE.ObjectOfViolation7, tbl_NTE.ClassPenalty7, 
tbl_NTE.CorrectiveActionPenalty7
FROM (tbl_Worker INNER JOIN ((tbl_PAH INNER JOIN tbl_NCA ON tbl_PAH.
[CaseIDNo] = tbl_NCA.[CaseIDNo]) INNER JOIN AdditionalFields ON 
tbl_NCA.CaseIDNo = AdditionalFields.CaseIDNo) ON tbl_Worker.WorkerID = 
tbl_NCA.NameOfIssuingManager) INNER JOIN tbl_NTE ON (tbl_NTE.CaseIDNo = 
tbl_PAH.CaseIDNo) AND (tbl_Worker.WorkerName = tbl_NTE.IssuingManager)
WHERE (((tbl_NTE.IssuingManager)=[Forms]![frm_Home]![txtUser]));
```

Comment: [frm_Home] has to be open when the query runs. You can make it invisible but it still has to be open for the query to see it.

Comment: @dbmitch the `frm_Home` is still open when I run my query but I still get error.

Comment: Well with the info you've provided it's hard to guess - open your query and view the SQL to copy/paste it back into your question

Comment: @dbmitch I've already added the sql code in the question. The Datasheet is located in a subform in `frm_Home` named `db_ALL_Subform.

Comment: By already you mean just yesterday, right? The datasheet in a subform in a form is interesting too. So you're saying the Recordsource property is set to the query name with the above SQL? When the Form `frm_Home` is open what happens when you run the query manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to avoid using form's field references in queries at all. If form closed, the query will request parameter, like most likely in your case.

Replace the reference by global function created in standard module. This function can store the name, for instance, in static/global variable or retrieve it from table. Main or login form can set this variable/table record once, then the form can be closed without affecting queries functionality

Answer (score 0):

Add another column and put the username. So when selecting the records, there's a condition where user='username'. They look all the data base on what the username has.

Answer (score 0):

your method is fine & correct; you just have some sort of cockpit implementation error

the criteria in the query should be: Forms!frm_Home.txtUser

you could have a spelling error in your form name or text box name

make the textbox visible and enter a valid entry and run the query manually

what you are getting appears to be a parameter prompt that means it cannot find the object i.e. form named frm_Home